# Nodes in a summing amplifier circuit

Tags: electrical-engineering

[image]

In the derivation for the gain of a summing amplifier, I have labelled nodes 1 and 2 as being 2 separate nodes. Is this correct? or do points 1 and 2 count as 1 overall node?

(Points 1 and 2 are the points circled)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Whether or not this labeling is "correct" depends entirely on **why** you used these labels and what you intend to do next.

Comment: You would then need an additional equation, viz; `V_2 = V_1`.

Comment: One overall node, but as comments have indicated, they can be separated to place emphasis on the high impedance negative terminal of op-amp, where I- = 0 and I3 = I4.

Answer (score 0):

They are the same node. You could slide them together and there would be no difference in the circuit. Use whichever format makes analysis easier.

Comment: While you are correct, I can see useful pedagogical reasons for separating the single electrical node into two halves. It looks like someone is trying to emphasize i3.